# courgette-jvm not able to download on JDK 11 project

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber-jvm

testCompile "io.github.prashant-ramcharan:courgette-jvm:5.12.0"

This on a gradle project using JDK 11 is giving below error:

````
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/5.0.1/guice-5.0.1-no_aop.jar```

https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1505

How can i get courgette-jvm to download.
````

Comment: In maven ,this is working fine for me  `<groupId>io.github.prashant-ramcharan</groupId>
    <artifactId>courgette-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>5.11.0</version>`

Comment: @user1207289 thanks, is it on JDK 11+ project?

Comment: Yes, jdk 13.0.2

Comment: Hmm it does not work on gradle, still looking for a workaround or fix :(

Comment: The error message you showed above is about Gradle not finding the artifact `guice-5.0.1-no_aop.jar`. There seems to be no special `no_aop` version of Guice anymore. See here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice501#some-highlights